# Old Movie Phasing

Tags: film, technical, phase, mixing, broadcast-standards

I have noticed that many older movies (Late 70's and before) shown on tv have a subltle phasing sound that runs thru the entire track.  It sounds like maybe the stereo track is being summed or is out of phase, but I'm not sure.  Anyone else notice this?  Anyone know what is going on?

David Rovin

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if it is an incorrect transfer at some point where the fill mix was combined with the M&E? That would phase almost constantly... Usually delivering stereo mix for TV, they put LR on tracks 1,2 and M&E on 3,4 of DigiBeta

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've noticed this, although not having TV might be why.

The only time I've come across anything close is the Region 2 DVD of Galaxy Quest. During the first convention scene there's a huge phase across the entire soundtrack.

Ian

Comment: Very curious. Maybe it could be a distribution fault on the disc? Or could one channel have been off a few samples and then back on? Like a clocking issue?

Comment: Not sure, it does it on every play. I don't know of anyone near me to compare their disc. Bought it far too long ago, something tells me HMV wont refund me. Either a disc or DVD authoring error as I doubt this happened in the sound mastering stage.